# How to customize a SwitchableFieldDefinition

Tags: content-management-system, field, magnolia

I have a `SwitchableFieldDefinition`.

I want to make different options:

1. one field
2. two fields
3. three fields

When I push the first option, it loads a field of the type `TextFieldDefinition` (for example), but I don't know if I select the second and third option because, for example, in the second option, I need to load a `TextFieldDefinition` and a `LinkField`, and in the third option I want to load three different fields.

[image]

This is the documentation, but I would like make children of my child.

I´ve been searching in demo magnolia, but I don't find something like this...

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For second and third option use CompositeField. Be sure to check what kind of transformer you configure for it to get desired resulting data structure in repository.

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, thanks to Jan for the support
[image: solution]

It´s funny the way is saved in the repository because concat the option and the name:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's how basic transformer saves the data. There are other ones that you could use that would store it in subnodes or using different naming patterns ... or you can even write your own if any of the available formats are not desirable.